# What is the default value of "proxyCredentialType"?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, wcf-security

I am doing a secure code review. Following are the two types of code I have got in an application :

CASE 1 : `<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm="" />`
CASE 2 : `<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" realm="" />`

I want to know if the proxyCredentialType has default value in case it not defined explicitly. What is realm ?

Comment: can you give the full binding specification, or at least the parent security settings?

Comment: Sorry Spodger. I cannot disclose that. Can you tell me if there is any default value for "proxyCredentialType" in case it is not defined anywhere else in code ?

And what are the possible instances where it could be defined explicitly other tha web.config ?

Comment: I don't know but it's only relevant depending on the parent security settings. Try looking here as a start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/transport-of-basichttpbinding

Comment: What in this case :
`<security  mode="None">`